# C fread not getting entire file

Tags: c, fread

I am trying to read binary files and storing the content into a char array. This function is working great for text files, but for non-text files (a PNG file for example) it does not work as expected. Below is the code followed by the results. What is wrong?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

unsigned int readFile(const char *fileName, char **contents);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *contents = 0;
    unsigned int length = readFile(argv[1], &contents);

    fprintf(stderr, "File length: %d\r\n", length);
    fprintf(stderr, "File contents:\r\n%s\r\n", contents);

    exit(0);
}

unsigned int readFile(const char *fileName, char **contents)
{
    struct stat stbuf;
    unsigned int length = 0;

    // Open a file descriptor
    int fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY);

    // Check that file descriptor was opened
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error: Failed to open the file for fstat (file: %s)!\r\n", fileName);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Get information from fstat
    if (fstat(fd, &stbuf) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error: Failed to find file length (file: %s)!\r\n", fileName);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Store the file length
    length = stbuf.st_size;

    // Close file descriptor
    if (close(fd) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error: Failed to close file descriptor (file: %s)!\r\n", fileName);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Check if the file contains data
    if (length > 0) {
        // Open the file for reading
        FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rb");

        // Check that the file was opened
        if (file != NULL) {
            freopen(fileName, "rb", file);
            // Prepare the contents variable
            *contents = 0;
            *contents = (char*)calloc(length + 1, sizeof(char));

            // Read the file and put it in the contents variable
            int lengthRead = fread(*contents, length, 1, file);

            // Check for file read error
            if (ferror(file)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error: Failed to read file (file: %s)!\r\n", fileName);
                exit(-1);
            }
            else if (lengthRead != 1 || strlen(*contents) < length) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error: File read error (file: %s)!\r\n", fileName);
                fprintf(stderr, "Characters expected: %d, Characters read: %d\r\n", length, strlen(*contents));
                fprintf(stderr, "Content read:\r\n%s\r\n", *contents);
                fprintf(stderr, "Aborting!\r\n", fileName);

                // Close file and exit
                fclose(file);
                exit(-1);
            }

            // Close binary file
            fclose(file);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error: Failed to open the file: %s!\r\n", fileName);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error: File was empty (file: %s)!\r\n", fileName);
        exit(-1);
    }

    return length;
}
```

Results:

```
devious@devious-kubuntu:~/Workspace/test$ ls                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
test  test.c  test.png  test.txt
devious@devious-kubuntu:~/Workspace/test$ ./test test.txt 
File length: 43
File contents:
This is a test file!

With multiple lines!

devious@devious-kubuntu:~/Workspace/test$ ./test test.png 
Fatal Error: File read error (file: test.png)!
Characters expected: 50243, Characters read: 8
Content read:
?PNG
¦

Aborting!
```

I would expect these results if I opened the file in text mode, but since it is opening in binary mode, I do not see why this is happening.

Comment: The file contains binary values, such as '\0' . Your strlen() counts upto the first NUL.

Comment: wildplasser is right. You are trying to read in a binary file like it's ascii and print out like it's ascii. You can't do that. You need to look up how to read binary files and then how to encode binary files for printout.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I will read more on how to read/write binary data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strlen` function is exclusively for use on C-style strings. There is no way to tell the length of arbitrary binary data by looking at its content. You have the length in `lengthRead`.

```
            fprintf(stderr, "Content read:\r\n%s\r\n", *contents);
```

Same problem here. The `%s` format specifier is for C-style strings, not arbitrary binary data. You'll need to write your own function to print the data in some appropriate format.

Comment: Ok, I see that I will need revisions. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.